# Loop to select rows until I reach a target number

Tags: python-3.x

I have two dataframes, which I join to see the active people. There are people who stop being active and I use one of the dataframes to fill the other one.

```
mass    pnr                                         freq
1        [40666303, 68229102, 35784905, 47603805]    4
54       [17182402]                                  1
234      [07694901, 35070201, 36765601]              3
```

The other table looks the same I just need to select enough people to reach my target of 7500-7600 people (40666303 - this is one person and 'freq' is the number of people in the list. It doesn't matter what is the 'mass', I just need when the sum of 'freq' is between 7500 and 7600 the process to stop. Now I need 400 people, but next month it is possible to need 20 people, it differs every month. Basically, my code now removes the non-active people and when it removes them i need to replace them with active. The first run of the process I used this code to select the initial 7500 people:

```
target = 7500
freq_sum = sum(mass_grouped3['freq'])
new_mass_not_in_whitelist1['records_to_select'] = [math.ceil(int((el * target ) / freq_sum )) for el in new_mass_not_in_whitelist1['freq']]
```

But now, with this code I am not getting the desired sum of people to fill the missing gap of 400 people. Also, it would be good to not select only the first rows, but maybe every other or some random condition. What can I change to work the way I explained?